# How to write a custom sort using SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite, sql-order-by, window-functions

I have a single table

```
Create Table Part(Part TEXT, Rev TEXT, DateCode Date, Unique(Part,Rev))
```

Is it possible to perform a custom sort by `DateCode DESC` but for the records with same `Part` should be grouped together for example result:

```
PART_1, B, 2022-02-14
PART_1, A, 1999-01-11
PART_2, C, 2000-02-24
PART_2, B, 1998-11-12
PART_2, A, 1998-11-10
```

My instinct tells me it must be done with

```
ORDER BY CASE WHEN....
```

But my knowledge is not good enough to continue. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `MAX()` window function in the `ORDER BY` clause to get the max `DateCode` of each part and sort by that descending:

```
SELECT *
FROM Part
ORDER BY MAX(DateCode) OVER (PARTITION BY Part) DESC,
         Part, -- just in case 2 different parts have the same max DateCode
         DateCode DESC;
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlite_3.27&fiddle=8fdb883f30e0288c4778690a78552662).

Comment: Thank you very much. This works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

To me it looks a simple case of sorting it by Part first and Date second

```
SELECT * FROM Part order by Part,DateCode Desc
```

Sqlfiddle for SQLlite for this case [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/2eb7de/2)
I think I am surely missing something ..